# google-apps-script ScriptProperties broken?

Tags: google-apps-script

Today my getScriptProperties() code is broken.  Here's my code:

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
fnameCol = scriptProperties.getProperty('fnameCol');
```

I guarantee you I have a script property called fnameCol, and the value is 2.  Yet this call returns 0.  This exact code used to work and for years (except for a single 4-hour stretch when the code broke due to an Apps Script server code update).  Now it fails on V8 and on Rhino.  Does anyone know of a problem with this today, Tue Sep 29, 2020?

Comment: What is the value returned by `fnamcol`? It it throws and error add it textualy. Also try to reproduce the problem and add a [mcve].

Comment: Hi Ruben. It doesn't throw an error.  It just returns 0.  That's the most minimal example I can do.  We have checked and double checked that the variable name string and property name in the script properties match exactly.  Bear in mind this code worked for over a year.  Today it doesn't.  I searched for any mention of this problem on the web today and there isn't any.  So that's why I posted this query.  I have no clue.

Comment: If it returns a value , it's likely not a bug. Your example is minimal, but not complete. To be complete, you need to provide a sample function demonstrating a code setting a value and retrieving another value. See [mcve]

Comment: What happens if you set it to 2 before you retrieve it? Does this occurr with only this script, or other scripts too? Try both old scripts and new scripts. Are you running this in Rhino or V8?

Comment: Follow the issue tracker for updates on this bug. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169458081

Comment: @Amit Agarwal - that is fundamentally the same problem!  PropertiesService is--or was--broken.  That's what I was wondering.  Thank you!  We solved our problem by hard coding the values and we're done with it.  This is the second time within 1 or 2 years we've been hit with Google's problems in PropertiesService.  This is not good.